# How do I add my own header file directory to Mac Terminal gcc?

Tags: c, macos, bash, shell, gcc

I'm trying to compile a C program (myProgram.c) that includes a custom .h file that is in a specified directory. How can I add the directory to gcc so that I can build myProgram.c anytime using just a command like `gcc myProgram` (*with no flags and what not*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by altering the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable, e.g.

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=~/include
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

You can add that to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or whatever to always have the environment variable set properly. [Here's a reference on how you can do the same for libraries and C++](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html).

Comment: Thx for the comment @Rafe Kettler. I tried this (usr/lib) as the path but I am still getting "No such file or directory" on compile...Where is the general place to put my custom header files so that gcc will always know about them?

Comment: @Eric wherever you want, really. I put mine in `~/include`, but the choice is yours.

Comment: @Eric.  If you used "usr/lib", you may want to try "/usr/lib" instead...but don't put header files in /usr/lib.  If you are going to do that, you may as well put them in /usr/include.

Answer (score 2):

had to use a whole set of flags to get this working on El Capitan:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/include
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/snappy-c.h"
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/snappy-c.h"
export CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/snappy-c.h"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
```

Answer (score 1):

Makefiles would be helpful in this situation, they ease the compilation of multiple file projects.

Assuming you are using these same files and they are in the same directory

- main.c
- custom.c
- custom.h

A sample makefile could look like

```
all: main.o custom.o
    gcc main.o custom.o -o myExecutable

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c

custom.o: custom.c custom.h
    gcc -c custom.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o myExecutable
```

Or something similar, the general format is

```
name: dependency
    command
```

So by running `make all` from the commandline you would be instructing the compiler to compile your source code into object files, and then link those object files together into an executable.

Make should be easily available on any modern system. For more information on basic makefiles and usage refer to this simple tutorial: http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/