# How to change file header in terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I have a file that should be a png but its signature is incorrect and therefore won't open. It's signature should be 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a but it is instead 8965 4e34 0d0a b0aa which makes it a .eN4 file. Is there any way to correct this in terminal?

Comment: Why specifically in the terminal?  The easiest way to do this would be with a hex-editor application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add my own header file directory to Mac Terminal gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697552/how-do-i-add-my-own-header-file-directory-to-mac-terminal-gcc)

Comment: @Alok Not a dupe of that question

Comment: Ok, where did you get it? What app created it? How do you know it's eN4? Is it otherwise compatible with PNG files? Why not just take the first 8 bytes off a normal PNG file and replace them using `dd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `xxd` to do this.

I have a Vim mapping for it, but you can also purely do it with `xxd` and your favourite editor:

```
xxd <bad_file >hexdump
```

Now edit `hexdump` with your favourite editor. It is important that you edit the hexadecimal part, not the ASCII column on the right, which is only FYI. After you're done, save the file and do:

```
xxd -r <hexdump >good_file
```

---

I guess you could do it in one go:

```
xxd <bad_file | sed '1 s/8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a/8965 4e34 0d0a b0aa/` | xxd -r >good_file
```